# Converting the mean and std of Normal distribution to the mean and std of lognormal distribution

Tags: normal-distribution, lognormal-distribution

**Hi**

I feel a little bit confused about transforming the parameters of normal distribution to log normal. 
I have a random variable that is N(0.06,0.000144). Because this random variable cannot take negative values, I want to use an equivalent lognormal distribution.
I calculated the mu (location parameter) as -2.83 and sigma squared (scale parameter) as 0.39. The model that I am using for simulation takes the mean and standard deviation of the lognormal distribution. when I calculate the mean and standard deviation of lognormal using the mu and sigma I get the original mean and standard deviation of the normal distribution. Is that correct?
Ps. I used the following formulas to calculate mu, sigma, mean and standard deviation of the lognormal:

[image]

Comment: Another solution, using more advanced techniques--but more general in scope--appears at http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/89970.