# How to find mean and variance of a transformation of a standard normal variable?

Tags: variance, mean

Let $N\sim N(0,1)$ and let $a$ and $b$ be some constants. Let $X$ be given as:
$$
X=a e^{-\frac{b^2}{2}+bN}
$$
**What is the mean and variance of $X$?**

I have been trying to find the distribution by using the information given here: [Exponential of a standard normal random variable](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/89970/exponential-of-a-standard-normal-random-variable) I have then found the mean  to be:
$$
E[ae^{-\frac{b^2}{2}}e^{bN}] =
ae^{-\frac{b^2}{2}}E[e^{bN}]=ae^{-\frac{b^2}{2}}e^{\frac{b^2}{2}}=a
$$
Bu I haven't been able to derive the variance.

Comment: Do you know the delta-method?

Comment: @financegrad Note that $ae^{-b^2/2} = e^k$ where $k=\log(a)-b^2/2$  and that $k+bN$ is also normal, so you are just exponentiating a normal and should be able to [apply results directly](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Log-normal_distribution#Arithmetic_moments). You can get exact mean and variance here (rather than asymptotic approximations) using standard results for the lognormal. Is this for some class?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As Glen_b noted the variance can be calculated exactly.

$$
\begin{align}
 \mathrm{Var}(ae^{\frac{-b^2}{2}}e^{bN}) & = a^2e^{-b^2}\mathrm{Var}(e^{bN})\\
& = a^2e^{-b^2}\left(\mathrm{E}[e^{2bN}]-\mathrm{E}[e^{bN}]^2\right)\\
& = a^2e^{-b^2} \left( e^{\frac{4b^2}{2}}- (e^{\frac{b^2}{2}})^2\right)\\
& = a^2e^{-b^2}\left(e^{2b^2} - e^{b^2}\right)\\
& = a^2e^{b^2}-a^2
\end{align}
$$

Comment: The question doesn't seem to be related to *averaging* at all, so it's not clear how a theorem about $g(\bar{X}_n)$ is useful

Comment: I just copied my cheat-notes on asymptotics. I guess the statement now makes more sense :) My bad!