# Can the error be modeled in the approximation of expectation

Tags: expected-value, conditional-expectation, approximation

I have a function $s(\omega)$ that is a sum of a function with random numbers $a_m$ and looks something like the following.

$$ s(\omega) = \sum_{m = 1}^{M} f(a_m, \omega) $$ where all the $a_m$ are draws from a probability distribution.

I have the expression of the expectation of the sum when $M \to \infty$
$$  \mathbb{E}\left[\sum_{m = 1}^{M} f(a_m, \omega)\right] = M \int_{-\infty}^{+\infty} f(x, \omega) p(x) dx   $$, I changed the parametrization of $x= a_m$ to write the integral.

However, in practical simulations, M is not infinity and in my simulations I suspect that this approximation doesn't give me exact results. That is the reason why I want to model the error in this approximation so that I can use it as a distribution over $g$ to fit it with the average estimate of the sum. Is there an existing way to do this?

========EDIT============

The function $f$ looks like the following

$$ f(a_m, \omega) =  \exp({-a_m \omega^2 }) $$

Where $a_m \sim \mathcal{N}(0, \sigma^2)$

Now if I want to know the expected value,
I write it as,

$$ \mathbb{E}\left[\sum_{m = 1}^{M}f(a_m, \omega)\right]_{M\to\infty} = M \int_{-\infty}^{-\infty} \exp({-x \omega^2 })\frac{1}{2\pi\sigma^2} \exp({-\frac{x^2}{2\sigma^2}}) dx $$

I hope the notations are clear now a bit. I’m not very confident with statistical terms, so, I say $a_m$ are random draws from a normal distribution and the function is a sum of values of a function that’s computed at these random numbers. For example, it’s a superposition of responses from $M$ different components.

Comment: Your notation is confusing. The second formula does not seem to have anything to do with expectation of a sum $s$.

Comment: If I have different realizations of $s$, the second formula is the expectation of $s$. Am I wrong?

Comment: Than your notation is not clear.

Comment: How should it be written?

Comment: I don't know what you are trying to say, so can't help.

Comment: I will try to reformulate.

Comment: Pardon! I indeed made a mistake. I wanted to know the expectation of the sum indeed and not $s$. I re-wrote it. Does it look clear now?

Comment: If the $a_m$ are not identically distributed then the equality 
$$\mathbb{E}\left[\sum_{m = 1}^{M} f(a_m, \omega)\right] = M \int_{-\infty}^{+\infty} f(x, \omega) p(x) dx $$
is not true. Do they follow the same distribution ? If so, what distribution is it ?

Comment: @StratosFair By simplifying the notation to use "$X$" in place of the random variable "$f(a_m,\omega)$" and without loss of generality (due to linearity of expectation) considering $m=1,$ the assertion is $E[X]=\int xp(x)\,\mathrm d x.$  In what sense is this "not true"? Have I perhaps oversimplified the question or misinterpreted it?

Comment: All the $a_m$ s are random draws from a Gaussian distribution.

Comment: Because $f$ is arbitrary, that does not give us any additional useful information: $f(a_m,\omega)$ could have (literally) any distribution whatsoever.

Comment: I will try to expand the question a bit more clearly with expressions of $f$ and what I have tried.

Comment: I have edited the question with more details.

Comment: Re the edit: it doesn't make sense, but perhaps you mean $f(x,\omega)=\exp(-x\omega^2)$?

Comment: Ah sorry. Let me edit it.

Comment: That narrows it down, because $s$ clearly is a sum of *iid* Lognormal values. Unfortunately, when $M\gt 1$ there is no closed form for its distribution.  You can still (easily) work out the moments of $s$ and compute measures of dispersion like the variance from those: see https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/89973/919.

Comment: @whuber in the link you provide, it gives an explanation of how the moments are computed. What I was interested to know is how to model the error in the approximated first moment itself. The approximation here is that $M \to \infty$. How to model the error when M is finite?

Comment: Could you elaborate on what you mean by "model the error"?  It's a random variable and surely computing its variance is basic information.  Where do you wish to go beyond that?

Comment: Correct me if I’m wrong. When we compute the variance of the mean or the expectation, we still assume $M \to \infty$. So, if we have multiple realisations of $s$, it’s mean is given by the last expression and the variance gives the information about how much it can vary around this expectation when we have multiple copies of $s$. However, in all these computations, still $M$ is considered to be a very high number. What I want to know is that if there’s a numerical way where we can define the error in the approximation of the expectation itself when $M$ is finite.

Comment: For example, something like this. $\epsilon = M \int_{-\infty}^{-\infty} \exp({-x \omega^2 })\frac{1}{2\pi\sigma^2} \exp({-\frac{x^2}{2\sigma^2}}) dx - \sum_{m=M+1}^{\infty} f(a_m, \omega)$

Comment: When we compute the variance, we always do it for *finite* $M$!  It cannot be computed for infinite $M:$ you have to take a limit -- but obviously this limit is infinite in your case.

Comment: Yes, my bad; the correct way of saying was when the limit of $M$ was infinite.