# Confused with notations about random variable and expectation

Tags: random-variable, expected-value, integral, sum

I asked a question originally [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/611345/can-the-error-be-modeled-in-the-approximation-of-expectation), but my notations were confusing and I couldn't convey properly in terms of statistics. Notations in statistics is a bit new to me, because my background is mostly related to deterministic sciences.

I have an i.i.d. random variable

$$ Y_1, Y_2, Y_3, ..., Y_M \sim \mathcal{N}(0, \sigma^2) $$

I have a function that uses this random variable as follows,

$$ X_i = f(Y_i) = \left| \frac{\sin\left(  N \frac{Y_i}{2} \right)}{\sin\left(\frac{Y_i}{2}\right)} \right|^2 $$

So, in principle, I can say that $X$ is also a random variable.

Then, I have another variable $Z$ that is also, in principle, a random variable.

$$ Z_l = \sum_{i = 1}^{M} X_i $$

Now I have a different number of $Z$; that is $L$. From prior experience, I know that the distribution of $Z$ is an exponential one.

$$ Z_1, Z_2, Z_3, ..., Z_L \sim \text{Exp}\left[ \frac{1}{F} \right]  $$

Where $F$ is the expectation of the random variable $Z$.

When I try to find an expression for $F$, I use the following integral. However, I use the assumption that $M$ is a large number.

$$ F = M \int_{-\infty}^{+\infty} f(y) p(y) dy $$

However, for a finite number of samples of $Z$, (that is $L$) and also probably $M$, the expectation of $Z$ itself would have some variance that should go to $0$ when $L \to \infty$. Basically, I want to know the distribution of the expectation of $Z$ instead of just having the expression above. Something like the following.

$$ \mathbb{E}[Z] \sim \Pi(F,  ...) $$

I wrote the first entry as $F$ to emphasize that it is the mean of the distribution. Additional information: I know what $M \int_{-\infty}^{+\infty} f(y) p(y) dy$ looks like in closed form.