PDF and moments for a linear transformation of multivariate lognormal
I have a multivariate lognormal variable $Y$ of dimension $d$. $Y=e^X$ where $X\sim N(\mu,\Sigma)$.
The PDF for the lognormal distribution in terms of $\mu$ and $\Sigma$ is:
$$
p(\vec{y}|\mu,\Sigma) = ((2\pi)^d|\Sigma|)^{-\frac{1}{2}}\Pi_i{y_i^{-1}}\exp\left\lbrack{(\ln(\vec{y}) - \mu)^T\Sigma^{-1}(\ln{(\vec{y})} - \mu))}\right\rbrack
$$
I'm looking for the pdf and moments of a third variable $Z$ where $Z=AY$ for a rectangular matrix $A \in R^{pxd}$ where $p<d$. Ultimately, I want to visualize the statistics of the "projected" variable $Z$– the distribution on the planar subspace– as one would plot the mean and covariance of a Gaussian.
Happy to answer any clarifying questions. Thanks in advance for any thoughts and guidance!
PS -- This is a nice writeup of the moment generating function for a multivariate lognormal variable, but it's unclear to me how to "cleanly" handle the linear transformation. This is a nice paper about lognormal distributions.

This doesn't seem encouraging! Help the mortals whuber...

Unfortunately, linear combinations of lognormals are rarely lognormal, so I wouldn't even attempt to compute the pdf.  The moments are no problem because those of $Y$ are directly related to $Z$ through the coefficients $A.$  See Zen's post at https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/89973/919 for the moments of $Y.$

Thanks for the reply. I realized the moments may be trivial but didn't want to bias someone chiming in: we can say that through linearity of expection that $E[Z] = E[AY] = AE[Y]$? Re: the pdf, thought so, but good to have confirmation. Since my goal is to visualize the 1st and 2nd moments of the projected lognormal, how would I visualize in $p$ dimensions the second moment? That is, what is the analogue for the covariance ellipsoid of the Gaussian for a lognormal...?

Consider visualizing the covariance matrix of the logarithms of the data!  Concerning linearity of expectation, that's covered in a recent thread. Some ways to visualize medium-dimensional covariance matrices are presented at https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/59446.

Totally, and I have some of the plots like you show (in 64 dimensions!), but in this application the log space really isn't very intuitive, unfortunately, while the data space is. I'm looking for an overlay-style visualization, hence the wish for the pdf of the projection (which I could use to, perhaps numerically, compute level sets). When $p$ is 2-dimensional and the data is Gaussian, we can plot nice 2D ellipsoids. I was hoping there might be a similar path for the lognormal projection.
Re linearity: kind of surprising that the pdf is challenging while the moments are so simple.

There is a concept in geological statistics called "conservation of lognormality" that says, under a broad range of circumstances, that linear combinations of lognormals are well approximated by lognormals.  You could check whether that's the case for your data. // To see why the pdf is difficult, simply try to work out the convolution of two independent standard Lognormal densities--you won't succeed.  Logs don't interact nicely with differences or sums.

Nice, thanks for the tip. If the projection looks lognormal, I would: log-transform, compute sample statistics, use those in the lognormal pdf, and find "clean" contours numerically using the pdf, or try to determine a contour analytically. Phew. I may just stick with my off-the-shelf density estimation from the data despite its ugliness. Thanks so much for your help!

That approximate property of sums of lognormals seems to have been noticed in a number of sciences, though it seems to get called something different each time. There's some references in the answers here: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/238529/the-sum-of-independent-lognormal-random-variables-appears-lognormal (there's a number of other posts that relate to this approximate rule of thumb)
